# Building Photran project with f2py

Tags: python, eclipse, fortran, f2py, photran

I'm trying to set up Photran to build my Fortran project with f2py in order to be able to call my Fortran function from Python (in PyDev, for the record). I've tried to set up an external builder, but this didn't work:

```
Location: C:\Python27\python.exe
Working Directory: ${workspace_loc:/<my_project>/bin/f2py}
Arguments: C:\Python27\Scripts\f2py.py
-c 
--verbose
--fcompiler=gnu95 
--compiler=mingw32 
-lmsvcr71
--build-dir ${workspace_loc:/FortranTDDexample/bin/f2py}
${build_files} -m <module_name>
```

This fails with the error `error: unknown file type '' (from 'D:\workspace\FortranTDDexample')`

I suspect that this isn't the best way forward and that a build configuration is more suitable (I'm very new to this).

So my questions are:

1) Has anyone documented a working setup for Photran and f2py?

2) Is there a way I can make my external builder (above) work?